# How to display text from inside a class

Tags: python, pygame, blit

I am trying to blit a 'P' as text onto a chessboard. Even following previous help on how to blit squares, I am not able to do it with text.

This variation of a chess game is played with pikemen, archers, and knights.
The 'P' stands for pikeman.

In future, I will display a sprite, but for the moment I would like to display letters (also, because it could be helpful for the GUI)

```
class Unit:
    def __init__(self):
        self.surface = pygame.Surface((100, 100))
        self.my_font = pygame.font.SysFont('Time New Roman', 18)
        self.img = self.my_font.render('P', 1, (255, 0, 0))
        self.surface.blit(self.img, (100, 100))
```

Basically what I am trying to do is to create a surface, set a font, render it, and blit it on the surface created.

Hereafter the full display code:

```
import pygame
import sys

from coordinator import coordinator

# Sets up the display

pygame.init()
window_size = (800, 800)
game_window = pygame.display.set_mode(size=window_size)
pygame.display.set_caption('My Game')




class WhiteSquare:
    def __init__(self):
        self.height = int(window_size[0] / 8)
        self.width = int(window_size[1] / 8)
        self.white_square = pygame.Surface((self.height, self.width))
        self.white_square.fill((255, 255, 255))


class BlackSquare:
    def __init__(self):
        self.height = int(window_size[0] / 8)
        self.width = int(window_size[1] / 8)
        self.black_square = pygame.Surface((self.height, self.width))
        self.black_square.fill((0, 0, 0))


class ChessBoard:
    def __init__(self):
        self.ws = ws
        self.bs = bs
        self.white_columns = white_columns
        self.black_columns = black_columns

    def draw(self):
        for columns in self.white_columns:
            game_window.blit(self.ws.white_square, columns)

        for columns in self.black_columns:
            for destination in columns:
                game_window.blit(self.bs.black_square, destination)


class Unit:
    def __init__(self):
        self.surface = pygame.Surface((100, 100))
        self.my_font = pygame.font.SysFont('Time New Roman', 18)
        self.img = self.my_font.render('P', 1, (255, 0, 0))
        self.surface.blit(self.img, (100, 100))


coordinator = coordinator()
black_columns = coordinator[2], coordinator[3]
white_columns = coordinator[0] + coordinator[1]

#print('coordinator' + str(coordinator))
#print('w_columns' + str(w_columns))


ws = WhiteSquare()
bs = BlackSquare()
cb = ChessBoard()
u = Unit()



# Event loop (outer)
while 1:

    # Event loop (inner)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()

    cb.draw()

    pygame.display.update()
```

Hopefully, it makes sense.

Thank you

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create `self.imag` in the constructor of `Unit`. But `blit` it in a `draw` method. The instance method `draw` has a parameter, which is the Surface, where the text has to be `blit` on:

```py
class Unit:
    def __init__(self):
        self.surface = pygame.Surface((100, 100))
        self.my_font = pygame.font.SysFont('Time New Roman', 18)
        self.img = self.my_font.render('P', 1, (255, 0, 0))

   def draw(self, surface):
        surface.blit(self.img, (100, 100))
```

Create an instance  (e.g. `u`) of the class `Unit`. Call `u.draw` in the main loop. The parameter to the `draw` method is the Surface which is associated to the display (`game_window`), so the text is drawn on the display. e.g.:

```py
u = Unit()
while 1:

    # Event loop (inner)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()

    # draw the scene
    cb.draw()
    u.draw(game_window)

    # update the display
    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need a draw function just like for the chess board. And then "paint" your custom font on the *game_window*.
This could look like such:

```
def draw(self):
    game_window.blit(self.img, (100, 100))
```

Complete unit class:

```
class Unit:
def __init__(self):
    self.surface = pygame.Surface((100, 100))
    self.my_font = pygame.font.SysFont('Time New Roman', 18)
    self.img = self.my_font.render('P', 1, (255, 0, 0))

def draw(self):
    game_window.blit(self.img, (100, 100))
```

and then use u.draw() inside your main loop

Comment: Thanks, Tobias. Your solution works as well. I have just picked Rabbid76's one because it is shorter, that's all.